# Swift: iBeacon Run a Code Before iOS Ends the Process

Tags: swift, ibeacon

I implemented iBeacon recognition in my project, everything works fine. When the application connects to the BLE device that has IBeacon, then I launch a whole process that sends data to a server.
I'm looking for a way to know when iOS kill the application after 10 seconds to perform one last action.
I'm looking at the functions in the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol, but I can not find a function that might look like willDisconnectApplication
How can I know a second before iOS kill my application to run a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a code snippet like below to track how much background time you have available.

Just by starting the background task shown, iOS will also give you extra background running time, so you get 180 seconds instead of 10 seconds.  After doing this, you also get to track when that time is about to expire by looking at `UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining`.

```
  private var backgroundTask: UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

  func extendBackgroundRunningTime() {
    if (self.backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid) {
      // if we are in here, that means the background task is already running.
      // don't restart it.
      return
    }    
    self.backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(withName: "DummyTask", expirationHandler: {
      NSLog("Background running expired by iOS.  Cannot detect beacons again until a new region event")
      UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
      self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
    })

    if threadStarted {
      NSLog("Background task thread already started.")
    }
    else {
      threadStarted = true
      DispatchQueue.global().async {
        let startedTime = Int(Date().timeIntervalSince1970) % 10000000
        NSLog("Background task thread started")
        while (true) {
          let backgroundTimeRemaining = UIApplication.shared.backgroundTimeRemaining;
          if (backgroundTimeRemaining < 200.0) {
            if (backgroundTimeRemaining.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 30) < 1) {
              NSLog("Thread \(startedTime) background time remaining: \(backgroundTimeRemaining)")
            }
            else {
              NSLog("Thread \(startedTime) background time remaining: \(backgroundTimeRemaining)")
            }
          }
          Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Where should I put this code in the didRangeBeacon delegate?

Comment: You add the part about `private var backgroundTask`  as a new class variable.  You add the method definition along with all your other methods.  Then you need to call extendBackgroundRunningTime() at least once when you set up beacon ranging or monitoring.